# What event is triggered if a google maps drawn circle is moved?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When you draw a circle in google maps api it has a point right in the center of it and when you move the circle by that point(if not by that point i get bounds changed and then center changed events) what kind of event is triggered ? 
I have tried "center_changed", "dragend", "bounds_changed", nothing is triggered if circle is moved by that point.

```
drawingManager.setDrawingMode($scope.G.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE);
drawingManager.set('circle',{
                        strokeWeight: 3,
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        fillColor: "red",
                        draggable: true,
                        geodesic: true,
                        editable: true,
                        suppressUndo: true
                    });
```

here's the code i set up drawing manager, and after that i just draw a circle on the map.

Pic:
[image]

Comment: Where is your code? How did you create that circle?

Comment: There is no such [event in the drawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer#drawing_events). You can possibly [use a Circle instead](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles) and make it draggable. Then you will have a [dragend event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#dragging_events) available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DrawingManager won't let you change the center until the circlecomplete event fires.  Add a 'center_changed' event listener to the circle when the 'circlecomplete event fires, use that to capture the changes of the center position.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'center_changed', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = circle.getCenter().toUrlValue(6);
    });
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KX9mc/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
      ]
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'center_changed', function(e) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = circle.getCenter().toUrlValue(6);
    });
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```